# dynamic items from dropdown in cypress js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, cypress

I want to select all the items in a dropdown list which doesn't stay in DOM for longer period and that also has a scroll bar.

I tried with finding the list, I caught the class but couldn't see if it has a list inside.
iI tried each() but its somehow selecting the 2 items from dropdown not all

Comment: Please provide a sample of the Cypress code you've attempted, the error messages you receive (if any), and a sample of the HTML code you're testing against.